# How to tell a compiler how to organise files?

Tags: android, compilation

I'm making an App in Android and I need to have organized files in `.apk` file.
I need to be able to tell which files they are responsible for.
When I have a project I can tell which classes are responsible for what (.java files) but when I have `.apk` file there are only .dex files.
For example, I want to be able to satisfy that:
Classes2.dex is responsible for cryptography,
Classes3.dex is responsible for network connection.

How can I tell a compiler how to organize files? Or there is another possibility?

Comment: i strongly doubt this is possible, i don't think anyone really evaluates what's inside their apk files, would be interesting to see if there's an answer to this

Comment: When I created a new library module in Android studio then inside of .apk file were two more files .dex. When I edited something in this new module, only this new files .dex changes. Maybe this is a solution?